# Range through functions

Tags: loops, go, func

I have 20+ functions that return either a struct or nil. I need to go through all of them and if they return a struct I append it to a slice of structs. So I would like to know if there is a way to iterate through all the functions and append the result if it is not nil because checking the result for every function seems to be a waste of time. Could anyone suggest a way to do this? Maybe an example or something.

Comment: You may list the functions in a slice and iterate over it, and call each. What have you tried? What problems do you have?

Comment: Oh wow, I did not know I can do that. thank you. I should be good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I know you kind of got the answer in the comments, but thought I'd put an example in anyway:

```
funcs := []func()*struct{Thing int}{
    func()*struct{Thing int}{return nil},
    func()*struct{Thing int}{
        newStruct := struct{Thing int}{Thing: 1}
        return &newStruct
    },
}

sliceOfStructs := []struct{Thing int}{}
for _,f := range funcs {
    res := f()
    if res != nil {
        sliceOfStructs = append(sliceOfStructs, *res)
    }
}
```